# Don't understand postlink in angular directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-directive

Hi all I'm trying to get hold of my directive's "expanded" DOM. That is, I want to be able to find and manipulate the DOM elements that are generated by the directive. I thought that the link or postlink functions were supposed to do that, but I keep finding the un-expanded version of my template (or at least, the stuff that ng-repeat should be generating isn't there.) Here's my example. Notice that the count of "li" elements is zero in both the pre and post link functions, but after the timeout, there are five. I need to find the five, but without the dirty tricks of timeout! What's the proper way to find this structure so I can work with it?

EDIT:

OK, I believe I've determined that what's happening is that the template has indeed been substituted into the element (actually, seemingly by the time the pre link function is called. The problem is that it hasn't been "evaluated" (I think this stage is what the docs rather oddly call "interpolated") even by the time the post link function is called.

That is, if I put, in the body of my pre, post, and timeout functions below, a call to print the inner html of the element, I get:

```
pre/post html is<ul><!-- ngRepeat: item in list --></ul>
```

but after the timeout there are are bunch of `<li>` elements. So, the question should really be "how do I get a callback after the template has been evaluated/interpolated?

(EDIT again, I've changed the code example below to be consistent with this new description!)

EDIT again to add suggested $compile (and use $timeout) I notice that this doesn't change anything. I think the problem is nothing to do with compilation as such, but to do with the expansion of the the ngRepeat, which seems to happen in a different "cycle" in some way.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html data-ng-app="MyModule">

<body data-ng-controller="MyController">
    <h1>Version 3</h1>
    <test></test>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        angular.module('MyModule', [])
            .controller('MyController', function ($scope) {
                $scope.list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
            })
            //.directive('test', function ($compile) {
            .directive('test', function ($compile, $timeout) {
                return {
                    template: '<ul><li ng-repeat=" item in list ">{{item}}</li></ul>',
                    compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
                        return {
                            pre: function preLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
                                //console.log('pre, li count is ' + iElement.find('li').length);
                                console.log('pre html is' + iElement.html()); 
                            },
                            post: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
                                //console.log('post, li count is ' + iElement.find('li').length);
                                console.log('post html is' + iElement.html());
                                 iElement.append($compile(this.template)(scope));
                                console.log('post-compile html is' + iElement.html());

                                //setTimeout(() =>
                                $timeout(() => 
                                  console.log('post timeout, li count is ' 
                                    //+ tElement.find('li').length),
                                    + tElement.html()),

                                    10, true);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };
            });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

TIA,
Toby

Comment: Heres a good post on [compile vs pre-link vs post-link](http://www.jvandemo.com/the-nitty-gritty-of-compile-and-link-functions-inside-angularjs-directives/), also, `link` and `post-link` are the same thing, if you just specify `link`, it's implicitly `post-link`

Comment: you are usng pre-compile and post-compile, not link

Comment: That's true Petr, sorry for being unclear. I started out using link, but got the exact same effect .I read some more, and tried the compile/pre/post thing, and got no change. You cannot, it seems, use both compile and link, since link gets ignored, so I had to make a choice for my illustration.

Comment: NexusDuck, thanks for the resource; so far, I've not been able to determine if my answer is in there. There's a lot of that article (and its follow up) and I'm not sure if you're indulging in good teaching (i.e. making me do the work) or if it's just another resource that might help me understand something in general? If you're sitting on a more specific pointer with the intention of letting me work it out, know that I'd be grateful for the chance to be just a little lazier :)

Comment: don't use `setTimeout` with angular, it's not angular aware.  use `$timeout` instead.  That being said, in your case, you probably should be using `$compile` to gain access to the compiled element, rather than the `link` functions. The result of the `link` functions is the HTML that will be appended to the DOM; they are the last place you can manipulate the HTML before the DOM is affected, rather than the first place you can access the modified DOM tree.

Comment: there is extensive documentation on the full compile process at https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler.  In particular, the section "How directives are compiled".  "// Step 1: parse HTML into DOM element ... // Step 2: compile the template ... // Step 3: link the compiled template with the scope. ... // Step 4: Append to DOM (optional)"

Comment: The description of how the `ng-repeat` directive works should be enlightening as well;  "the compile phase where all of the directives are identified and sorted by priority, and a linking phase where any work which "links" a specific instance of the scope and the specific instance of an `<li>` is performed." "`ngRepeat` works by preventing the compilation process from descending into the `<li>` element so it can make a clone of the original and handle inserting and removing DOM nodes itself."

Comment: Claies, thanks for the input. 1) yes, I know I cheated with setTimeout, it was a hack to prove a point, but it's good that you called it out here, lest others think it's a good idea later. 2) That's a lot of understanding I need to build to find out how to get a callback after ngRepeat "completes" (and I realize it might well complete multiple times as the DOM changes. However, any chance you can short circuit that for me and give me a specific pointer to how to pick up on that callback? I'm having great difficulty with the amount of information I seem to need to handle to make this work.

Comment: Oh, also, I tried to use $compile, but it created an infinite loop and stack overflow, so clearly, if that's the answer, I need help there instead!

Comment: it would be easier to give you a less broad answer about the process as a whole if you can show exactly what you plan on doing with the DOM elements, other than just log their contents.  There may be more efficient ways to achieve your goal.  However, I did post an answer that might give you some additional clues.

Answer (score 1):

In your `link` function, you can use the `$compile` service to "complete" the compilation process.  something like the following:

```js
return {
  link: function(scope, element) {
    var template = '<ul><li ng-repeat=" item in list ">{{item}}</li></ul>';
    var linkFn = $compile(template);
    var content = linkFn(scope);
    element.append(content);
  }
}
```

This will produce a complete DOM element that can be traversed.  you can either modify `content` before appending it, or `element` after the `content` has been appended.

You will frequently see the shorthand of this process, i.e.:

`var content = $compile(template)(scope);`

Comment: Thanks so much for your efforts Claies, I tried to put the change I think you're suggesting into the code (it's now in the main example) but it doesn't change anything. Unless I misunderstood your suggestion, I think the problem is that the ngRepeat looks like it gets processed separately, long after the compile completes.

I also not, which seems to support this, that the template has been included in the output I'm seeing, but has been changed to use a comment form of the ngRepeat directive, which is not what was in the original.

Comment: But since you ask why I'm doing this here goes. The real use (rather than this minimum illustration) is to be a list of items with delete buttons. I want to build a map that ties the keys on the delete buttons (originally indexes, but they cease to be as items are deleted) to the html elements that need to be $animate.leave()-ed. I guess I could just search for the enclosing html element that contains the button that was pressed, but it seemed like a good idea to have it all set up in advance. Plus, it seems like a reasonable thing to want to do...

Comment: I think the problem I'm having is that the link mechanism, and all its variants are intended to handle the preparation and use of the *directive*. What I'm actually trying to do is to handle the expansion of the ngRepeat, which is a whole different story, essentially unrelated, and happens later. In effect, what I'm really trying to achieve would require me to be messing with the link function of the ngRepeat directive, not of my enclosing template directive. 

Still kinda feels like if I understood the lifecycle properly, I could make it happen, but I guess for now, I'll go a diferent route

Comment: The main question I have is why you are trying to modify the HTML after your directive renders the repeat, when you could just integrate what you want into the repeat template.

Comment: I'm not actually trying to modify the HTML, I'm trying to parse it (well, that's a bit grandiose--I'm trying to find out what was put there). I tried to describe the ultimate functional goal a couple of comments back (and have indeed got my code to work properly using the alternative approach I outlined there). But it seems, conceptually, like it should be possible, and there would be other use cases for, being able to find out what was generated, once, immediately after generation, rather than having to wait 'till interacting with that generated code and doing the analysis then.